# a non trivial example: $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need a non trivial  examples of group isomorphism that maps $G\to H$ such that 
 $G/H \cong G$.

Comment: By $G\setminus H$, do you mean the quotient $G/H$? And do you want it to be isomorphic to $G$ (as in your title) or $H$ (as in your body)?

Comment: sorry for mistake , yes I meant the quotient groups  by G/H 
& I want isomorphic to G @ChrisEagle

Comment: There are examples that aren't direct products. Such a the [prufer group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicyclic_group) but these are more complicated in nature.

Comment: The same question has been asked 10 times on math.SE ;)

Answer (score 6):

For both the title and the text of the question, you can take $G=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\dots$ (an infinite product) and 
$H=\mathbb Z\times\{0\}\times\mathbb Z\times\{0\}\times\dots$.  Then all three of $G$, $H$, and $G/H$ are isomorphic.  (You can replace all the $\mathbb Z$'s by your favorite other group to get more examples.)

Comment: E is my favourite group :(

Answer (score 5):

The first finitely generated example found was the Baumslag-Solitar group $G = \langle x,y \mid y^{-1}x^2y = x^3 \rangle$, with $H$ equal to the normal closure in $G$ of $w^2x^{-1}$, where $w=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$.

So $G/H \cong \langle x,y,w \mid y^{-1}x^2y = x^3, w = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy, x=w^2 \rangle$.

Eliminating $x$, using $x=w^2$, gives

$G/H \cong \langle y,w \mid y^{-1}w^4y = w^6, w = w^{-2}y^{-1}w^2y \rangle = \langle y,w \mid y^{-1}w^2y=w^3 \rangle \cong G$

(because $y^{-1}w^2y=w^3$ implies $y^{-1}w^4y = w^6$, so that relation is redundant).

That's all reasonably straightforward but, although it seems very plausible that $H$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $G$, that does need to be proved, and you need the theory of HNN extensions to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

One additional example, as the OP asked for a group defined without direct products: fix a prime $p$ and let $T_p=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\exists n\hspace{3pt}z^{p^n}=1\}$. Let $\varphi:T_p\to T_p$ be defined by $\varphi(z)=z^p$. Then $\varphi$ is a epimorphism (surjective homomorphism) which is not injective, i.e. $\ker(\varphi)\neq\{1\}$, and $T_p/\ker(\varphi)\cong T_p$.