# Is it possible that $A \approx B$ but $A/B \not \approx (e)$?

Tags: group-theory

If we have two isomorphic groups $A$ and $B$, where $B\subset A$, is it possible that $A/B \not \approx (e)$? Obviously, $A$ and $B$ are infinite.

Comment: This has been answered also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323664/a-non-trivial-example-g-h-is-isomorphic-to-g).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots$ and let $B=\{0\}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots$

This example shows that $A/B$ can be anything you want by replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ with an arbitrary group.

Answer (score 0):

How about $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $B = 2\mathbb{Z}$, so that $A/B = \mathbb{Z}/2$?